# Lucene Indexing - using a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, lucene

I have an incremental index on a shared hosting server. I would have used a console application to perform the indexing by the hosting provider does not allow console apps on the server.

I am thinking of using a web service to do the indexing (with some queuing mechanism). Is this a good idea? What are the pros/cons or alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) does it all for you.